# how to declare a free length 2d array in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Good day,

Normally I create 2D array as follow :

```
string [,] arr = new string [9,4];
```

This is a 2D array with 9 rows and 4 columns.

I would like to ask, how to create 2D array with any length.
For example, that is not nessecary to set the row to 9, it can be any number, depends on the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about simple `List<List<T>>` ?

This is like a concept, you naturally can wrap up this in your custom class, so consumer of your API don't see these wiered nested declarations.

```
public class Matrix {

   private mtx = new List<List<T>>(); 


   public void Append(T value) {
      .....
   }  

   public void InsertAt(T value, int row, int column) {
      ....
   }

}
```

Comment: since you're wrapping the thing, wouldn't it be more memory-efficient to have just a single List<T> with a size x*y, and to calculate proper offset when accessing elements?

Comment: *may be* yes, but you spend much more time on traversal of that list for picking required (if needed) values from given *row* and *column*. And it becomes hard to manage, especially in cases when the matrix should become non symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

For that you must be using a `List<List<string>>` instance. Now you can dynamically add anything you want, however this also has the disadvantage over the array format that you need to check for yourself if you have reached the maximum number of rows or columns.

Answer (score 0):

This `Matrix` class is space (based on access pattern) and performance efficient:

```
class Matrix<T>
{
    readonly Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>> _rows = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, T>>();

    public T this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            var row = ExpandOrGet(j);
            if (!row.ContainsKey(i)) row[i] = default(T);

            UpdateSize(i, j);

            return row[i];
        }
        set
        {
            ExpandOrGet(j);
            _rows[j][i] = value;

            UpdateSize(i, j);
        }
    }

    void UpdateSize(int i, int j)
    {
        if (j > SizeRows) SizeRows = j;
        if (i > SizeColums) SizeColums = i;
    }

    public int SizeRows { get; private set; }
    public int SizeColums { get; private set; }

    Dictionary<int, T> ExpandOrGet(int j)
    {
        Dictionary<int, T> result = null;

        if (!_rows.ContainsKey(j))
        {
            result = new Dictionary<int, T>();
            _rows[j] = result;
        }
        else result = _rows[j];

        return result;
    }
}
```

Although you can add further utilities to facilitate your workflow.

Comment: that's a pretty c# conversion for a MATLAB sparse matrix.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson Is that a good thing or a bad thing? (I have not used MATLAB since 90's.)

Comment: it is a special thing: a sparse matrix has its use, but the user has to be aware of the pros of cons of a sparse matrix. pros: small memory footprint for very large bounds with few data inside, cons: an horrible bloat if the matrix is not sparse at all !